# Created a symlink but Finder shows it as an Alias

Tags: macos, terminal, backup, alias

When I try to backup my iPhone, iTunes gives me an error, saying that it cannot make a Backup because the backup is damaged or not compatible.
To move the backup folder I have followed the steps as below:

1. Copy the Backup folder from the original path to the MacintoshHD
2. Change the name of the original folder (From backup to backup-old) to try to avoid conflicts
3. Run the command

   ```
   ln -s /MacintoshHD/Backup ~/Library/"Application Support"/MobileSync
   ```

At the end of the process the Mac creates me a backup alias file (the icon looks like a data file with a little arrow on the corner). By the way, when I hit the "get info" option of the alias file, it shows me that the path is on my SSD?!
Sorry guys, I'm quite new and I'm trying to learn something about the terminal.

Answer (score 4):

Finder always shows symlinks as aliases. Even though they are actually different, Finder does not show the difference, regarding all symlinks as aliases.

Answer (score 1):

The "ln" command doesn't copy or backup anything it just makes a link to it in a different place. Is that what you were trying to do? If you are trying to create a backup you need to use "rsync", or "cp" to copy the files for a backup.

Comment: I was just trying to move my iphone backup folder from my SSD to another HD. I have read that the best way to do that is the symlink

Comment: I believe the command works just fine. You should have an alias (if you use the Finder to look at it) in your MobileSync folder called "Backup" that should point to /MacintoshHD/Backup. iTunes should now store your iPhone backups on your MacintoshHD drive. Make sure you quit iTunes an restart it. Maybe try logging out and back in or best yet restart the computer.

Comment: I did it, and I really do not understand why iTunes gives me the error message "Can't backup because the backup is damaged! But I am trying to create a backup!! Do you think it's because I have Yosemite? I have read about some problem with this version. Thanks

Anyway I will try to follow your suggestion and restart after the command is done.